# Rails query with distinct

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have having a tough time figuring out how to query my database correctly.

My query is like the following:

```
@events = Event.where("startdate > '#{now}'")
```

There is a column in the events model called `name`, I need to return all the events whose `name` is distinct, but I also need ALL the columns. How would I accomplish this?

I thought that this would work but it isn't:

```
@events = Event.where("startdate > '#{now}'").uniq
```

Then I realized that it has no idea what to look at to judge uniqueness, how do I tell unique to look at the name column to judge uniqueness?

Data:

```
ID | Name         | Description  | start
1    christmas      holiday        12-25-16
2    christmas      holiday        12-25-17  
3    thanksgiving   holiday        11-24-16
```

Should return

```
1    christmas      holiday        12-25-16
3    thanksgiving   holiday        11-24-16
```

thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "whose name is distinct"? Just one event if there are more events with the same name? Is this correct?

Comment: Eddited, yes there is a column named "name"

Comment: And so, in that case, one random event from the events with the same name?

Comment: @Ursus See edit. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a block to say to `uniq` how to do the work

```
@events = Event.where("startdate > '#{now}'").uniq(&:name)
```

Otherwise, and probably this is better, you could do all in SQL, because 
`uniq` is not, it iterates your resultset.

```
@events = Event.where("startdate > '#{now}'").group(:name)
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Answer (score 0):

You can have the query run in the following manner:

```
@event = Event.where("startdate > '#{now}'").uniq(:name)
```

this will be able to give you data with only unique entries.